# Maintain sound with key pressed?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi I'm using the Soundpool Android to play a sound when I press a button. I wonder if it is possible to maintain this sound playing while the button is pressed.

Comment: yes. simply use onTouchEvent and look in the event if it is up or down

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to identify the touch events I mean ACTION_DOWN when the button is pressed and ACTION_UP when the user has lifted his finger. You can start playing the sound in when the ACTION_DOWN event occurs and stop it when the ACTION_UP events occur. 
Now for catching these events on a button you will have to set onTouch listener on the button and implement it's onTouch() method. onTouch() method is where you will have to catch those events and play/pause the sound.

Here is a sample how you can implement this onTouch() method of the button:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //here you can start playing song
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //here you can stop playing song
                    break;
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here you can notice that I have returned false to indicate the os that I am finished with the event and now you can handle the event. If you do not want the os to handle the touch event then return true which indicates that you have consumed the touch event.

I hope this will help.